# Redirecting root / home page to custom page screws up all other redirects in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I’ve merged 2 websites into one. I’ve set up .htaccess redirects for all the pages on the deactivated site (hkgolf.co.uk) to redirect their equivalent on other site (http://harriskalinka.com).

This is what I have and in the .htaccess on deactivated site:

```
Redirect 301 / http://harriskalinka.com/
Redirect 301 /work/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
Redirect 301 /projects_tag/academy/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
Redirect 301 /projects_tag/asia/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
```

What I like’d like to do is have visitors that got to the old website’s home page be redirected to a page on the new site telling why they have been redirected and for all the other redirects to work as normal. So i did this:

```
Redirect 301 / http://harriskalinka.com/home/hk-golf-redirect/
Redirect 301 /work/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
Redirect 301 /projects_tag/academy/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
Redirect 301 /projects_tag/asia/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
```

What happens now is that if you go to old sites home page (hkgolf.co.uk/) you are redirected to http://harriskalinka.com/home/hk-golf-redirect/ (what I want)

The problem is that is if you got to hkgolf.co.uk/work/ you are sent to http://harriskalinka.com/home/hk-golf-redirect/work/ instead of http://harriskalinka.com/work/

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your rules to keep generic rule (catch-all) at the last:

```
Redirect 301 /work/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
Redirect 301 /projects_tag/academy/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
Redirect 301 /projects_tag/asia/ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
Redirect 301 / http://harriskalinka.com/home/hk-golf-redirect/
```

Alternatively you can use `RedirectMatch` to have regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/work/?$ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/projects_tag/academy/?$ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/projects_tag/asia/?$ http://harriskalinka.com/work/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ http://harriskalinka.com/home/hk-golf-redirect/
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this also mean I have to use the same thing for sub folders so:  

  
`Redirect 301 /blog/golf-industry/ http://harriskalinka.com/blog/golf-stuff/`
  
should come before:  
  
    `Redirect 301 /blog/ http://harriskalinka.com/blog/`